# Transform numbers with 0 values at the beginning

Tags: sas

I have the following dataset:

```
DATA survey; 
 INPUT zip_code number; 
 DATALINES; 
 1212 12
 1213 23
 1214 23
 ; 
 PROC PRINT; RUN;
```

I want to link this data to another table but the thing is that the numbers in the other table are stored in the following format: 0012, 0023, 0023.

So I am looking for a way to do the following:

- Check how long the number is
- If length = 1, add 3 0 values to the beginning
- If length = 2, add 2 0 values to the beginning

Any thoughts on how I can get this working?

Answer (score 2):

Numbers are numbers so if the other table has the field as a number then you don't need to do anything. 13 = 0013 = 13.00 = ....

If the other table actually has a character variable then you need to convert one or the other.

```
char_number = put(number, Z4.);
number = input(char_number, 4.);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `z#.` formats to accomplish this:

```
DATA survey; 
 INPUT zip_code number; 
 DATALINES; 
 1212 12
 1213 23
 1214 23
 9999 999
 8888 8
 ; 

data survey2;   
    set survey;
    number_long = put(number, z4.);
run;
```

Comment: It depends on whether the numbers in the other table are stored as character or just formatted as `z#`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need it to be four characters long, then you could do it like this:

```
want = put(input(number,best32.),z4.);
```